# Difference between "cross with you" and "angry with you"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, differences

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between 'I'm cross with you' and 'I'm angry with you'?

I have the feeling that *being cross with someone* (by the way, can you be cross 'at'? or is one always cross 'with'?) is more used in Britain than in the US. Is that correct?

Comment: For those of you who don't know that famous joke about nuns in Transylvania.  Have a look [here](http://fun.twilightwap.com/joke.asp?joke_id=241).

Comment: Yes, AmE speakers wouldn't recognize 'cross' to mean something like 'anger'.

Comment: @Mitch: We sure as hell would. Don't make me cross with you!

Comment: @Robusto: :) OK. Sure, maybe 'not recognize' is too strong, but to my ears it sounds like something from British children's books from before WWII. I can't imagine that coming out of an AmE speaker's mouth nowadays.

Comment: It does make me think of Mary Poppins.

Comment: Very British this idiom of yours «being cross with someone». Find and read the novel by Penny Vincenzi, The Best of Times, and then you get to know how the expression fits in the language. You may encounter many other expressions from the kingdom...Enjoy!

Answer (score 9):

*Cross* is similar to *angry*, only less intense. It is used to express anger at minor matters.

> You left the cream out all night. Now I'm cross with you.

vs.

> She left me for another man. I was so angry with her I wanted to scream.

Comment: And can you be cross at something/someone ? I think Yes, though it may sound a little awkward.

Comment: @n0nChun, the idiom is that you're cross *with* someone. "Cross *at* someone" just sounds... awkward.

Comment: @n0nChun: Well, you could also be cross *about* something.

Answer (score 0):

To be *cross* implies *irritability*, with a potential response that is vaguely *out of proportion*, and surprising, given the nature of the transgression.

> The Latin professor is a fair teacher,
>   but don't cross him.

[This link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cross) hints at a nautical term, possibly stemming from cross-winds (?), though I am speculating on that.

Comment: "Don't cross him" is a somewhat different idiom than "being cross at someone."

Comment: If you cross someone, they might be cross with you, but yeah, it's more likely they'd be angry or furious.